# Running multiple ASP.NET websites on same port and IP

Tags: asp.net, nginx

I want run multiple ASP.NET websites on a single IIS server using the **same IP address** and **port (80)**.

I cannot use host headers to accomplish this because my clients have not agreed to use a domain name.

My websites will be accessed using an IP like 227.23.32.44. All of them will use the same port (80). The reason for this is, I have around seven applications and my clients wants me to use standard, IANA approved, easy to remember port numbers.

If I want to go with standard, IANA approved TCP port numbers, I would be left with
227.23.32.44:80
227.23.32.44:116
227.23.32.44:84

This is not very user friendly.

Rather, if I use
227.23.32.44:80
227.23.32.44:81
227.23.32.44:82
Then it is much more user friendly but my clients will not let me use this.

Is there any other way to run multiple websites? Can I use another proxy server to inspect the url of all incoming requests and then route to the necessary application?  I have heard about nginx. Can I use nginx to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to uniquely identify a site using a composite key of IP+Host Header+Port.

Since host header is out, you are left with just IP and Port. You have 2 options.

1.Have multiple adapters so that you have multiple IPs and port will be 80.

2.Have same IP but different Ports

Host header is meant precisely for this reason. You can have same IP,  same port but different Host header.

Nginx is not a silver bullet either.  You won't be able to run ASP.NET on Nginx.

Comment: Your question was already clear. My answer remains the same. You cannot have multiple sites running on the same port and same IP. Either the port has to be different or the IP. If both are same, host header has to be different. Since you can't use host headers, you must make decisions appropriately.

Comment: Cant I use a separate routing application? In that case I will have my sites running on same IP, different ports. But all the end users will hit port 80. Routing application running on port 80 will route to the necessary application

Comment: You can use anything that works for you. The answer is to the question that you asked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to put applications in different folders on IIS?

- 227.23.32.44/WebApp1
- 227.23.32.44/WebApp2
- 227.23.32.44/WebApi

IIS support this out of the box:

1. Go to IIS Manager
2. Right-click Default Web Site
3. Choose "Add Application..." command. Alias means customer visible part of URL.